# Caracter "<" me rompe el mensaje en php

Tags: php, string

Tengo un campo de búsqueda en mi sitio, que cuando el usuario termina de ingresar algo va a buscar dicho término a una BD de MySQL. Si hay coincidencia se muestra el resultado al usuario y sino se visualiza un mensaje. El problema lo tengo con este último. Pero que sólo se da con un carácter especial, que es el **"<"**.

Es que si el usuario ingresa por ejemplo "seoo" sale el siguiente mensaje: *"El término **seoo** no existe o fue ingresado de manera incorrecta, verifíquelo."*

Pero ahora si ingresa **"<seo"** (porque sin querer el usuario tecleó el carácter **"<"**) sale el mensaje: *"El término   "*. Y no pone nada más. Se rompe el mensaje y sólo muestra lo que viene antes de **<seo**. Porque el mensaje debería quedar: *"El término **<seo** no existe o fue ingresado de manera incorrecta, verifíquelo".* La idea es que el usuario pueda ver y resaltado su ingreso.

En php la línea la tengo así:

```
<?php echo "El término <strong>".$Nombre."</strong> no existe o fue ingresado de manera incorrecta, verifíquelo.";?>
```

Les cuento que también e intentado sacar el tag `<strong></strong>` (que está dentro del mensaje), pero pasa lo mismo. También aclaro que no quiero reemplazar o no poner el carácter **"<"**, quiero que salga tal cual ingreso el usuario.

Quizás hay alguna función de *PHP* que me permita envolver de alguna manera esa variable `$Nombre`.

Comment: Intenta usando comillas simples en lugar de comillas dobles, algo así: `<?php echo 'El término <strong>'.$Nombre.'</strong> no existe o fue ingresado de manera incorrecta, verifíquelo.';?>`

Comment: Sospecho que tendrás que crear una función para analizar la cadena buscando caracteres especiales, y sustituirlos si los encuentra. [En esta página](https://www.hazunaweb.com/curso-de-html/caracteres-especiales/) hay una lista de estos caracteres.

Comment: @JosueArriola Me olvide de comentar que también ya había probado con comillas simples y es lo mismo. Inclusive con *print* en vez de *echo*.

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras Como bien digo al final de mi consulta, la idea no es sustituirlo por ninguno. Quiero que salga dicho caracter también.

Comment: @DamianGarcia ya comprendí, había entendido mal la pregunta, intenta entonces usando `htmlspecialchars($Nombre)`. Saludos.

Comment: Se llama sustituir porque, para que html lo muestre como debe ser, lo debes cambiar. El usuario lo verá tal cual lo escribió. para html `<` es un caracter especial que abre una etiqueta, por lo que no mostrará nada de lo que hay a partir de él hasta que encuentre un `>` que cierre "la etiqueta". En cambio, si tú escribes `&gt;` el navegador lo interpretará e imprimirá como `<`. Saludos!

Comment: Una solución rápida: `$nombre = (strpos('*'.$nombre, '<') > 0) ? str_replace('<', '&#60;', $nombre) : $nombre;`. Se usa "*". para hacer más intuitiva la validación de la presencia del caracter problemático.

Answer (score 2):

En las páginas recientes se pone como codificación `utf-8` para que todo texto ingresado/mostrado se entienda esta en este formato lo que evita lo que mencionas.

Claro eso implica que tus datos desde su origen fueron ingresados con esta configuración o si fue acción directa a la BD fueron ingresados como tal.

Otra opción es que uses [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php) de php para que se haga la conversión respectiva y así evitar esos detalles. De tal forma que quedaría:

```
<?php echo "El término <strong>".htmlspecialchars($Nombre)."</strong> no existe o fue ingresado de manera incorrecta, verifíquelo.";?>
```